# Detect if a Chrome extension is installed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to detect if a Chrome extension is installed in user's browser. If not, I want to display a link to install the extension. If it is already installed, I want to hide the link.

This seems like a possible solution but I am confused what some_object_to_send_on_connect is supposed to be?
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#global-events

```
var myPort=chrome.extension.connect('jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida', some_object_to_send_on_connect);
```

Comment: Sorry, that question is still the place to ask. The answer you quote is outdated: this method does not exist anymore. Check BJury's answer for an up-to-date and more complete version.

Comment: @simple Do you solve this problem? could you please share your solution? I think `chrome.management` is undefined in javascript

Answer (score 10):

I know it's an old question, but since I managed to solve this problem (for my needs) I'd like to share.

I accomplished this by adding some info into the DOM. In extension's `content.js` file I have:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute('extension-installed', true);
```

And in my page:

```
var isInstalled = document.documentElement.getAttribute('extension-installed');

if (isInstalled) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hello @Leo Tavares, here you can find a guide on how format your answers on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Thanks, @AlejandroMontilla (Y)

Comment: You're Welcome!!

Comment: somehow, this is the simpler solution ever provided! :D Nice and clean. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you want to check from a web page or from an already installed extension.

**From a web page**

You can't.  Only Chrome Web Store can check that.

But if you write the extension and the web page, you could make your extension execute some content script in you page to confirm its installed and working.

**From an extension**

Provided you know the extension's id you are looking for, you can use

```
chrome.management.get(id, callback);
```

You can use chrome.management.getAll() to get a list of installed extensions, with more info than their id.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management

Comment: it is not work and return this error: `cannot read property get of undefined` also I have management permission in my manifest.

Comment: It seems the browser isn't recongnizing chrome.management, or perhaps you misspelled it.  Please refer to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-get

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are the author of the extension, you can include a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) within your `extension.js` file, and within your site you can `addEventListener` to that event.

Within your extension:

```
const customEvent = new CustomEvent('myExtensionCheckEvent', {
    detail: true // whatever value you enter here will be passed in the event
})
document.dispatchEvent(customEvent)
```

And your sites javascript file:

```
document.addEventListener('myExtensionCheckEvent', e => {
    if (e.detail) {
        // the extension is installed
    }
})
```

Note that the key must be called `detail`.